# To run the google app campaign to promote iOS app and track downloads, What Configurations needs to setup from the iOS app end

Tags: ios, google-analytics-campaign-builder

[image: See the screenshot]

I have configured the firebase inside the iOS application and linked firebase with google ads account. Import the firebase "first_open" event for the conversion tracking and publish the app campaign. Android app campaign running but for the iOS app there is no impression from the last 2 weeks. Do i missed any kind of configuration from the app end?

1. AppTrackingTransparency permission is needed ?
2. App campaign will take more time to get impressions on iOS app campaign?

Google ads app campaign will work and start receiving the impressions and track app install.